# How does –PKGSTYLESHEETMODE=1 work

Tags: hp-exstream

I created an HP Extreme package without this setting and it cause a huge black box to appear on my output. After packaging with `–PKGSTYLESHEETMODE=1` enabled, it seems to have fixed the problem. No one in my area know exactly what this switch does, we were just told to use it when the black box happens.

Can anyone explain what this does and how it affects the actual package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find someone with a manual. There are 3 different options for -PKGSTYLESHEETMODE. =1 means that stylesheets will be included to a package regardless of that what approval status the stylesheet is current in. EX: You can do an approved package with a WIP stylesheet and it will still work.